# JavaScript escape from multiple quotes

Tags: javascript, escaping

I'm basically trying to put `this.name` instead of "main" tag. Could not find a way to do it on javascript since quotes messes it up.

Code:

```
document.querySelector('button[name="main"]').classList.add('selected');
```

Comment: this should work: document.querySelector('button[name='+this.name+']').classList.add('selected').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :
`document.querySelector('button[name='+this.name+']').classList.add('selected');`

Comment: Note that this may not work if `this.name` has a space in it.

Answer (score 0):

Just check

```
var obj = document.querySelector('button[name="main"]');
alert(obj);
```

It is working, the problem is in you `classlist.add('selected')` part